# Unsure what the elements of the A/R (equivalence class) in this question

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory, equivalence-relations

[image: picture of question]

I believe the elements of $A/R$ are $\{0,2\}$, $\{1\}$ and $A/R = \{\{0,2\},\{1\}\}$.  Continuing with the second part of the question, I believe that that set comes out to be
$$
\{ (\{0,2\}, 0), (\{0,2\}, 2), (\{1\}, 1) \}.
$$
But, since I am unsure about the first part, the second part may not be correct.

Comment: It may help to have the questions reworded for you into a bit more plain of English.  The first question is asking you to find the set of equivalence classes.  The second question is asking you to find all ways in which you can pick a single "representative" from each equivalence class.

Comment: that helps me understand it a lot better.  thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The set of equivalence classes is correct.

Now you have to find the maps $f\colon A/R \to A$ such that $f(x)\in x$. A map $f\colon A/R\to A$ is determined by specifying the image of each element in the domain and there are nine of them.

If we set $e=\{0,2\}$ and $o=\{1\}$, we have some restrictions for a map to be in the set: we need $f(e)\in e$, so either $f(e)=0$ or $f(e)=2$; moreover $f(o)\in o$ is the same as $f(o)=1$. Thus we have just two maps satisfying the requirement.

If you want to describe the maps as sets of ordered pairs, the functions are
$$
\{(e,0),(o,1)\}\qquad\text{and}\qquad\{(e,2),(o,1)\}
$$
so your set is
$$
\bigl\{ \{(\{0,2\},0),(\{1\},1)\},\{(\{0,2\},2),(\{1\},1)\}\bigr\}
$$

Comment: thank you!  I forgot that it was asking for all the functions.